# Count Previous Record if Condition is met on Current Record

Tags: crystal-reports

So I am displaying a number of different events from user tasks.

I want to display the task previously if a certain task is recorded in the table.

For example

```
NAMEID  EVENT   BEGTIME   ENDTIME   ITEM    LOCATION

User1   Pick    10:00AM   10:05AM   Item 3  LocationA
User1   Pack    10:06AM   10:07AM   
User1   Pick    10:08AM   10:09AM   Item 4  LocationB
```

So if I have the above data... If the event is a pack, I want to display the pack record and the previous record as well so that would be the Pick at 10:00AM, not the Pick at 10:08.

Any ideas how I would go about doing that... I don't know how to tell crystal reports to look at previous record.

Thank you

Comment: Use function Previous(field)

Comment: Great! That worked... thanks for the quick response. Next question - how do I pull multiple fields? Do I need to do multiple functions?